# Vanilla JavaScript - How to check a option is selected in multiple select options?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, dom-events, multiple-select

To check whether a **checkbox** is ticked we do this:

```
let isChecked = event.target.checked
```

What about a **multiple select options** like this below?

```
<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

How can we check if A is selected or when A is unselected when you select B?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way multiple-selection elements work with values, simply check the new value. If it's `A`, then the first selected element is `A`.

```js
document.getElementById("books").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  console.log(this.value == "A");
});
```

```html
<select name="books[]" id="books" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem @laukok, always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length of selected option:

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.clear();
  let sel = this;
  let checked = [...sel.options].filter(option => option.selected).map(o => o.value);
  let isA = checked.includes('A') ? 'A selected' : 'A not selected';
  let isChecked = checked.length > 0 ? 'Selected' : 'None selected';
  console.log(isA);
  console.log(isChecked);
});
```

```html
<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```